# Using lists with the CSV module in python

Tags: python, csv

```
file = open("Class A.csv")
    csv_file = csv.reader(file)
    List=[]
    List.append(csv_file)
    average_list=[]
    for i in csv_file:
        score1 = int(i[1])
        score2 = int(i[2])
```

When this code is ran I'm given this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Task 3 code.py", line 82, in <module>
    Class_A()
  File "E:/Task 3 code.py", line 21, in Class_A
    score2 = int(i[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I believed it was because there was no values on the second line of my spreadsheet however there is and I believed this error was caused by a calling a value that's not present in a list however I'm unsure in this case

Comment: You are adding your entire csv file to a single entry of the list in `List.append(csv_file)` and then it's not used again? Other than that, my guess would be that you're using index 1 and 2 in your for loop and you mean to be using 0 (the first entry) and 1 (the second entry)? Without seeing your file it's hard to say.

Comment: You should provide an example of the data you are trying to process and what you expect the code to do. Currently it's not possible to understand what your intended output is; there's lots of ambiguity, and problems with indentation in the example code.

Comment: Hi can you show how looks your csv. Remenber you start counting from 0 . do you have something in your third column  ?

Comment: At least one of your rows does not have three columns.

Comment: Thanks guys it was because my third column was empty, is there a way I could stop writing the lines to a list if the line is empty. Because I'd like all the values to be considered without creating lots of score versions

Comment: @Ian again, I would suggest that you edit your question to reflect what you are trying to do because the second sentence of that comment doesn't make much sense without context. I took a stab in the dark, but your code still has parts that don't make sense and now we find that your objective is expanding. It doesn't matter if your question gets quite a bit longer for it, people will read it and it will be far easier to provide a full answer for you.